# How do I pull 2 dates from a string variable?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string with two dates included. I looked at a .Split and a .Substring function. Not sure I was going the most efficient route.  Is there a clean way to pull the dates from the string?

```
string test = "Hello World.  Random date1 is 12/10/2010. Now 4 days later is 12/14/2010."
```

Comment: Are the dates always the same format, or can they vary?

Comment: Is the text (other than the dates) random or always the same?

Comment: The text is the same.  The format is the same... date.ToShortDateString()

Comment: You may want to define efficient/clean. Do you mean simplest in terms of expression, or efficient in terms of processing speed, or most generic in terms of possible strings handled ... ?

Comment: Note that the string returned by `ToShortDateString()` is going to differ from one locale to the next, and the user can change his date/time format as well.  If you want this to work reliably, then you shouldn't use `ToShortDateString()`, but rather use `DateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`.

Comment: You may also look at the public domain C# Date Time Parser ( http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/date_time_parser_cs.aspx ). It returns an object containing whether a date/time was found, the first date/time found, and its position in the string. It looks for multiple date/time formats. To get additional dates from a string would require some modification, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the date format will not change, you could do something like this:

```
private static readonly Regex dateRegex = new Regex(@"\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}");

public static IEnumerable<string> ExtractDates(string str)
{
    return dateRegex.Matches(str).Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value);
}
```

Then use it like:

```
foreach (var dateString in ExtractDates("...")) {
    // ...
}
```

Tested and working against your example string.

Comment: I am not sure how the loadtime is for this as opposed to other methods.  But it is very clean and effective.  Thanks!

Comment: @user54197: Regular expressions may not be fast, but if there are performance issues with the application, I doubt this will be the bottleneck.

Comment: I found a few instances where the format is mm/d/yyyy and m/dd/yyyy.  Is there a way to tweak the regex for multiple conditions?

Comment: @user54197: Yes, I have updated my answer with a different regex to handle those formats (in addition to the original format).

Answer (score 0):

If it's actually alternatives you're interested in, and the string format does't change, you could:

```
string[] dates = test.Replace("Hello World. Random date1 is ", "").Replace("Now 4 days later is ", " ").Split(" ");
```

or just split on the text that doesn't change.

Comment: The data is being pulled from a database.

Comment: Why aren't the dates stored in the database as dates instead of strings?

Comment: Ah -- which data, the whole string? You could actually parse it in SQL if you're pulling from, say, SQL Server. But it seems strange that they're not being stored as dates and then the string constructed afterwards. But that may be another question ...

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression would be the most general way but, depending on the content around the dates, may be difficult to get right. It would potentially be very clean but could also be pretty ugly. On the plus side, you can guarantee that it's always going to be only a few lines of code and it's easy to change.

If your dates are always at specific indices in the string then you can use `substring`, but if (for example) you could have `Now 10 days later...` then that won't work very well.

`Split` will work if you know that each date is always the nth word in the string.

EDIT: Just saw your comment about the text and format always being the same. I'd use `split` or a regex like `Hello world.  Random date1 is (\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d). Now \d+ days later is (\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d)`. (I know, you could make that more concise. But it'll work. I think.)

EDIT2: A more concise regex after a bit more thought: `.*?(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}).*?(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})`. This will let you change the surrounding text without needing to update the regex.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky question.  You could do something like this:

```
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();

string test = "Hello World.  Random date1 is 12/10/2010. Now 4 days later is 12/14/2010."
var potentialDates = test.Split(" .",StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string s in potentialDates)
{
  DateTime d;
  if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "MM/dd/yyyy", out d))
  {
    dates.Add(d);
  }
}
```

This could probably be linq-ified, but it should work ok as is.  As long as the dates are as indicated, this should work find.  If you have time as well or if your date format includes `'.'`, then you might want to modify the Split to only split on space.  You could probably trim leading and trailing punctuation and be ok.  Maybe something like this:

```
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();

string test = "Hello World.  Random date1 is 12/10/2010. Now 4 days later is 12/14/2010."
var potentialDates = test.Split(" ",StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string s in potentialDates)
{
  DateTime d;
  if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s.Trim(',', '.', ';', ':'), "MM/dd/yyyy", out d))
  {
    dates.Add(d);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Regular Expression

```
public void SampleRegexUsage()
{
    string regex = @"\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}";
    RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline;
    string input = @"Hello World.  Random date1 is 12/10/2010. Now 4 days later is 12/14/2010.";

    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, regex, options);
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);

        Console.WriteLine(":" + match.Groups[""].Value);

    }
}
```